# How to disable SSL 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: windows-10, ssl

I have disabled SSL 2.0 and 3.0 on a Windows 10 PC in our environment as described in the articles linked below, but for some reason this PC is still being flagged by our security software (Nessus) for SSL 2.0 and 3.0.

https://help.duo.com/s/article/3400?language=en_US

https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm

I looked at the PC again and verified that the registry keys are still set correctly. With SSL disabled in the registry in this way, is it even possible for anything on the computer to turn on or otherwise use SSL 2.0/3.0? My understanding is that any application that needs it will simply stop working.

In response to Ramhound's questions:

- Browsers in use on this PC: Primarily Chrome, but IE and Edge are also present.
- Indications of SSL2/SSL3 use: This PC is being flagged by Nessus for SSL2/SSL3 vulerability.  The scan results really don't tell me anything besides the fact that SSL2/SSL3 were detected.

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: How about we start with the basics?  What browser are you using?  What makes you think SSL2 and SSL3 is being used.  Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all indicate websites over anything except TLS 1.2+ are insecure.  Instead of replying with a comment, please edit your question, and include this vital information.  For us to answer any question we need to know what Nessus is reporting.  You can sanitize the information if you need to do that, provided the information required to answer your question from the report, is provided in your question body.

Comment: If the app is visible to Nessus it has an open port, list all applications that have an open TCP port and check each application if it is an outdated version that uses SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the protocols in the registry only affects applications which are actually using the Windows TLS stack. Not affected by these settings are for example Chrome (using BoringSSL), Firefox (using NSS), Python, Ruby, Nodejs ... (all using OpenSSL) etc. But all current versions of these libraries have SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0 either by default or have it not even built in anymore. So whatever you see (which is unknown) might be some older application.